# Listing the selected slide index numbers

Tags: vba, powerpoint, slide

I have a large presentation and I'm looking to select a number of slides positioned a different positions and receive a list of the slide index numbers.  My idea is for this list to appear in a  message box.

So far I have put together the below which gives me each slide number in different message boxes.  I'm looking for a list to appear in 1 message box that I can copy and paste into an email.

Ideally I'd like to add some extra text to the message box so I can copy and paste to a pre made email.  I can probably take that part on though.

Any help would be greatly received.

```vb
Sub ShowMeSlideNumbers()

Dim oSld As Slide

For Each oSld In ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange

MsgBox "The slide index of the current slide is:" & oSld.SlideIndex

Next oSld

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating an array to store the selected index numbers. Then read the array numbers back in reverse order to create a string. Finally, display that string as part of a MsgBox:

```
Sub ShowMeSlideNumbers()
    Dim oSld As Slide
    Dim X As Integer, Y As Integer, arrSlideNumbers() As Integer
    Dim strSlideNumbers As String
    
    X = 0
    
    For Each oSld In ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange
        ReDim Preserve arrSlideNumbers(X)
        arrSlideNumbers(X) = oSld.SlideIndex
        X = X + 1
    Next oSld
    For Y = UBound(arrSlideNumbers) To 2 Step -1
        strSlideNumbers = strSlideNumbers & CStr(arrSlideNumbers(Y)) & ", "
    Next Y
    strSlideNumbers = strSlideNumbers & CStr(arrSlideNumbers(1)) & " and "
    strSlideNumbers = strSlideNumbers & CStr(arrSlideNumbers(0))
    MsgBox "The slide indices of the selected slides are: " & strSlideNumbers & "."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple mod of your existing code should do it:

```
Sub ShowMeSlideNumbers()

Dim oSld As Slide
Dim sTemp as string

For Each oSld In ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange

sTemp = sTemp & "The slide index of the current slide is:" & oSld.SlideIndex & VbCRLF

Next oSld

MsgBox sTemp

End Sub
```